# How to select class and tag in css?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to select an element only if it satisfies both a class *and* a tag? For example, in the code below, I would like to only select the 2nd line of text:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Apple</p>
    <p class="foo">Banana</p>
</div>
```

Using the `<p>` tag will select both lines, and using the `.foo` class will select both the text and the `<div>`. Is there a way to define a css rule that combines both? Like "`p && .foo {...}`", or something along those lines.

Comment: so you need to target only `p` tag with `foo` class?

Comment: This question shows zero effort put into solving problem before posting it.

Comment: If you literally tried using the code you suggested (`p && .foo {}`) *(without the ampersands `&`)* it would have worked. Furthermore, if you simply googled for "css selectors" you would have easily found an answer. I voted to close the question for *"very low quality"*

Comment: @Rawrplus Without the ampersands, a beginner is likely to try `p .foo`. The question is not low quality, **it explains the problem, gives an attempt and a reproduction**. It's a beginner question, but that doesn't make it low quality. Without knowing the technical names ("selector", "modifier", etc.) it's difficult to search for the terms. Please stop harassing people whenever they ask basic things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p.foo { color: red; }` does the job. Combines element (`p`) and class (`foo`).

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)  you can find more information about different CSS selectors.

#### Snippet

```css
p.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <p>Apple</p>
    <p class="foo">Banana</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`p.foo { ...` is what you're looking for.

EDIT: to demonstrate:

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p.foo {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <p>Apple</p>
    <p class="foo">Banana</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select what you need.

```
<style>
p.foo {color: black;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to combine tag and class in a `.` rule.  try this:

```
p.foo {
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cam combine selectors but putting nothing between them, which would be `p.foo` in your case. The empty space between `p` and `.foo` is technically one of the combinators in CSS and there a few.

For example, you could do `element.class#id[attribute=value]`. This will match all elements with tag name `element`, with a class `class`, with the id `id` and with an attribute named `attribute` whose value is `value`. For example, this guy:

```
<element class="class foo bar" id="id" attribute="value"></element>
```

You can read more about [selectors and combinators here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).