# Why can't I call my css hyperlink styling class from my html code?

Tags: html, css

I want to create multiple classes for hyperlink styles.

I want to have a default class as well as a special class for a navigation menu.

Here's my css code:

```
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-items a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I'm trying to call the "menu-items" class in html but it keeps using the default a{} style shown above.

Here's the html code:

```
<div class="container-outside">
    <div class="container-inside">
        <ul class="ul-list">
            <li>
                <a class="menu-items" href="temperature.html">Temperature</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Weight</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Currency</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried removing the default class and creating two special classes without any success. Kinda at a loss here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select class and tag in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639828/how-to-select-class-and-tag-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your selector isn't right, becuase `menu-items` isn't `a`s parent.you should select your tag like this:

```
a.menu-items {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put the class name .menu-items

```
<div class="container-outside">
    <div class="container-inside">
        <ul class="ul-list">
            <li>
                <a class="menu-items" href="temperature.html">Temperature</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Weight</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Currency</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> 

CSS


 a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .menu-items  {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```